# use = instead of AS in sql?

Tags: t-sql

I just learned today that we can use = in SELECT, such as (tested in sql-server)

```
SELECT [new_col_1] = [col_1]
    ,[new_col_2] = [col_1] + 1
    ,[new_col_3] = CASE WHEN [col_1] > 0 THEN ‘Y’ ELSE ‘N’ END
    FROM [dbo].[table_1]
```

I think this looks neater than `[col_1] AS [new_col_1]`. Why most code I see uses AS? Does = only work in some of the sql systems? Thanks

Comment: Personal preference - they do the same thing.  Personally, I think using `As` is cleaner, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: There are several ways you can alias a column.  `AS` is the original in the standard, I'm pretty sure `=` has not been added.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) is a nice little article explaining.

Comment: yes sql-server is one of the only ones that supports the notation of ColumnAlias = Some definition.  I prefer it as well but if you are going to port your code between rdbms it is best to stick with the ANSI standard of AS ColumnAlias

Comment: I see only a disadvantage using = considering that it's not supported by all RDBMS while AS is.